# json decode fail

Tags: json

Can any one help: why json decode fail to decode this string?:

```
[["34372",0,0,190.94614747307494,11.804232804232774,"201","","1","0","no","0","","2394","381","",null,"group_indl_1"],["34373",0,0,190.94614747307494,11.804232804232774,"201","free_text","1","0","no","0","381","2395","382","<span startpoint=\"0\" color=\"0,0,0,0\" pt=\"35\" idfont=\"3\" style=\"font-size: 35px;\">Home essentials</span><span startpoint=\"15\" color=\"0,0,0,0\" pt=\"35\" idfont=\"4\" style=\"font-size: 35px;\">  Save up to 75%</span><span startpoint=\"32\" color=\"0,0,0,0\" pt=\"9\" idfont=\"Zapf Dingbats-Regular\" style=\"font-size: 9px;\">s</span><span startpoint=\"33\" color=\"0,0,0,0\" pt=\"14\" idfont=\"4\" style=\"font-size: 14px;\">    </span>",null,"indl_1_0"]]
```

Comment: Using what language and what JSON library?

Comment: php 5.2.6, json 1.2.1. http://www.jsonlint.com/ says it's valid but for php not

Comment: PHP seems to be handling it fine:  http://codepad.org/VBylBSf5

Comment: What you've posted appears to be valid JSON. You can verify it agains tools like that at http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or

Comment: So what's the error message? Or why do you believe it fails?

Comment: it fails, return value is NULL

Comment: did you compare the posted string with the original? some details might be "lost in translation"

Answer (score 1):

I found the error: Some strange chars like long minus get problmes. I remove it and has no problem.